# Finishing Time in DFS, is that necessary?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

According to DFS algorithm for graph traversing:

```
DFS(G)
  for each v ∈ V (G)
      v.mark = false
  time = 0
  for each v ∈ G.V
      if not v.mark
         DFS-Visit(v)
```

```
DFS-Visit(v)
   v.mark = true
   time = time + 1
   v.d = time
   for each (v, w) ∈ E(G)
      if w.mark == false
              w.parent = v
              DFS-Visit(w)
   time = time + 1
   v.f = time
```

Where v.d and v.f are start and final meet time of vertex "v".
**Question:**
Why should we use v.d and v.f? I cannot see the impact of the time in the pseudo code.Its just been incrementing and intializing to something but haven't been used by any **if** or **for** condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those markings give a pre-ordering and a post-ordering respectively. They are indeed not used by the DFS algorithm per se.

There are several applications, one of them being that the reverse post-order is a topological sort. It can help finding strongly connected components efficiently.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#DFS_ordering) for some details.

Comment: If the goal is to only traversing the graph and nothing else,should we use starting and ending time?

Comment: @program_craft No, you can skip those if you just want to do a graph traversal (for example for testing connectivity in an undirected graph). The same can be said with the `.parent` marking. It can be used to find paths in the graph, but is not necessary for the graph traversal. However, the `.mark` is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks ,I wanted this.